# Running MPI program on linux makefile

Tags: c++, linux, mpi

How can I execute I MPI c++ file on linux? I compile with:

```
mpic++ myprog.cpp -o myprog
```

but I don't know how to run the file... and how can I choose the number of processor?

Comment: try `mpirun -np 4 myprog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute an MPI program in parallel, you use `mpiexec`. Typically, you can use something like this:

```
mpiexec -n <num_procs> ./myprog
```

You'll usually also want to include a list of hosts on which to run your processes. This argument varies based on which MPI implementation you have. For MPICH (and derivatives such as MS-MPI, IBM's MPI implementations, Intel MPI, Cray MPI, etc.), it's:

```
mpiexec -n <num_procs> -hosts host1,host2 ./myprog
```

For Open MPI, it looks like this:

```
mpiexec -n <num_procs> -host host1,host2 ./myprog
```

It's possible that some of these have alternate versions that are more compatible between implementations, but I don't remember off the top of my head.